# how to align text center in nsMenuItem Cocoa Mac osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new in MAC OS X development, I have to align text centre in `nsMenuItem` but I not find any particular solution. I checked on google but not find any tutorial.

Find some tutorial but not exactly same, in these tutorial we take a `NSView` in `nsMenuItem` and then Insert `subview` in `NSVIEW` to accomplish it centre align.

Is there is any better solution? Please provide me link if possible.

Edit : I attached screen shot, but this is not working for me.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Attributed String of the menu item, which does allow you to center the text, as well as change the font, color and size of the text as well.

I do not know which version of Xcode/OSX you are using, but under Xcode 5.0.2 you can use the built-in interface builder to edit the attributed strings of menu items.

Click the MainMenu.xib entry, then click the menu you want to edit to open it, then click the menu entry. On the right side of the window there should be some options, if not click the right most square in the group of 3 at the top right of the Xcode window [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuOdD.png).

Once you have the right panel open click the Attributes Inspector icon [2] (4th from the left, looks like a slider type icon). At the bottom of the list of attributes you will see an entry for "Attrib. Title" [3].

That is where you can set a custom font, color and alignment for your menu item.

If you need more control then that provides, you can also embed custom NSViews into your menus which gives you complete control over how the menu will look.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, I already done same, but nsmenuItem not centered, please check the screen shot i attached in question.

Comment: Fill in the box below the font and alignment options, that is the attributed text string field, which can be different than the standard text string.

Comment: Hello, please have a look on my similar question .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628267/default-font-name-in-cocoa-for-nsmenuitem