# Get default font name in Cocoa for NSMenuItem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I am using NSAttributed NSString in my NSMenuItem, but it's Font is changed as compare to default font, I wants to use default font for Attributed string.

Can any one explain, how to find or fetch the default Font for NSMenuItems.

Right now I am using this :
[image: sample image]

```
 NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor blackColor],
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle

                                 };
```

Thanks

Comment: NSFont offers systemFont - have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, I used this

```
NSFont *oldFont = [menu font];
NSLog(@"%@",oldFont.familyName);
```

and used like this

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" size:14],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor blackColor],
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle

                                 };
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the default font of an `NSMenuItem` just use the method `[NSFont menuBarFontOfSize:0]`.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont menuBarFontOfSize:0],
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor blackColor],
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };
```

which is easier in all ways.